# how to use mono to compile .sln file under linux

Tags: .net, linux, mono

## something I have try

1. I use xBuild to compile solution file, but it does not generate a .exe file.
2. I don't know so how can i do with solution file, and if compile it with xBuild, why .exe not generated. Any help is appreciated?

Comment: Are you looking under the project output `bin` directory? Getting any errors while `xbuild` is running?

Comment: What kind of solution? xbuild does not compile all solutions.